# How can I exclude a particular category from my Wordpress Page 1 and Page 2?

Tags: categories, homepage, exclude

I have 2 pages in the Wordpress site. All 2 pages are showing posts. I need to restrict few categories in First Page and other few categories from Second Page.

```
 <?php
    function excludeCat($query) {
      if ( $query->is_home ) {
        $query->set('cat', '-3,-5,-23');
      }
      return $query;
    }
    add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'excludeCat');
    ?>
```

This one will not work because, It will block the category from all the 2 pages.

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there, all that is left is to check on which page you currently are.

In the following code I'm first creating an array where the key corresponds to the page number and the value are the categories to exclude. This results in only one time writing `$query->set(...`. And to be really sure that a value exists for the key, I added `isset()`.

```
<?php
function excludeCat($query) {
    $page = get_query_var('paged', 1);

    $exclude = [
        1 => '-3,-5,-23',
        2 => '...',
    ];

    if ($query->is_home && isset($exclude[$page])) {
         $query->set('cat', $exclude[$page]);
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'excludeCat');
```

Comment: In this line :   $page = get_query_var('paged', 1);, Is the 1 is Page ID?

Comment: @Sajeev No, if you [check the docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/), you'll see, that the `1` is the default value. If no `paged` is set, it returns `1`, otherwise it will return the current page from 2+

Comment: It didnt worked for me. the below is my code:  function excludeCat($query) {
    $page = get_query_var('paged', 1);

    $exclude = [
        12 => '-152',
        8  => '-152'
  11 => '15'
    ];

    if ($query->is_home && isset($exclude[$page])) {
         $query->set('cat', $exclude[$page]);
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'excludeCat');